# Problem with two fancybox iframes

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I need:

1. On clicking a link, open up a fancybox on an iframe (faqs.htm)
2. On clinking some link in the faqs.htm, I need to close this fancybox and open up a new one (new.htm) in iframe

If showNew() is the function to do this, my code is

function showNew()
{
        parent.$.fancybox.close();
        parent.window.setTimeout("parent.$('#new').fancybox().trigger('click')",500);
}

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to close the previous fancybox first.

This should do the trick :

```
function showNew() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        parent.$('#new').trigger('click');
    }, 500);
}
```